# AirDrop photo from iPhone to Macbook Pro says "waiting…" then "rejected"

Tags: iphone, airdrop

What I'm doing:

1. Open Photos on iPhone (7 plus, iOS 10.2.0)
2. Tap share icon
3. Wait for my laptop identity to appear in AirDrop section
4. Tap on my own face  (i.e., laptop identity)

Result:

- My face says, "Waiting…"
- After what I assume is a timeout delay, my face says, "Declined"

The MacBook Pro has `Allow me to be discovered by:` set to `Everyone`. The top Google search results seem to suggest logging out of iCloud, then back in, but it takes forever to reinstall everything, so I'd *really* rather not. ☹️

Answer (score 17):

***SOLUTION***

ok after months of this on occasionally then off mostly and sat with the waiting. I found the solution

VPN, do you have any VPN like expressvpn or similar on your mac, if so turn it off and voila .

Comment: OMG, thank you! I didn't notice that I was connected to our corporate VPN server.

Comment: You're my hero!

Comment: I had to disconnect the VPN on both my iPhone and Mac for it to work but it worked. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I solved this:

1. Open the `Control Panel` on iPhone(Swipe up from bottom or Swipe down from right for newer models)
2. Toggle on-off the bluetooth & wifi

And now AirDrop works. Wish the iPhone would automatically cycle the wireless antennae when this kind of thing happens…but at least I don't have to wait hours for all my iCloud content to re-sync.

Comment: This also worked for me between an iPad Mini 6 (iOS 15) and a Macbook Pro 2017 (Big Sur). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by switching one device to a different wifi "router". I have 2.4Ghz & 5Ghz channels on my router, so I just connected my Mac to the 5Ghz and iPhone to 2.4Ghz, and then suddenly I got like 10 copies of the files I was trying to transfer.

Nothing else worked. Rebooting didn't work. Toggling Wifi on and off didn't work. Just this.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that the firewall blocks the transfer.

Make sure that `sharingd` is allowed to receive incoming connections.

Comment: Pls. elaborate.

Comment: @greatvovan you can find the firewall settings in the security & privacy section.

Answer (score 0):

Airdrop can be very frustrating when it does not work as expected or seem to work randomly.

I think i messed up with the firewall a few times ago and somes rules obviously messed up with Airdrop.

In my case the Graal finally came when i installed Murus ( https://www.murusfirewall.com/murus/ same devs from IceFloor ) it allows you to interact with PF ( Packet Filter ) which is the native OS X firewall.

In Murus, i did "Load Selected Profile" with "Less restrictive" in the "Assistant" tab, then click the play icon on the top left and voilà ! Miracle happened !

PS : the Murus Lite (free) edition is enough for this manipulation

Answer (score 0):

Together with the VPN that is stopping Airdrop, also the Mac Firewall turned ON can be the reason for this problem.

By turning it OFF for a moment it is possible to make Airdrop work. This can be configured in **System Preference > Security & Privacy > Firewall > Turn Off Firewall**.

Alternatively, instead of turning Firewall OFF you can just allow incoming connection for the `sharingd` service.

Answer (score 0):

For me, powering off Bluetooth and Wi-Fi radios, and resetting `bluetoothd` *usually* fixes things without requiring a reboot. I wrote a small bash script to facilitate this, in case it's useful to anyone:

[`airdropfix.sh` - github gist](https://gist.github.com/luckman212/efec7df3fdea3163341ebbb7144c8415)

The script requires [blueutil](https://github.com/toy/blueutil). (`brew install blueutil`)